# Email to Salesforce: Is it possible to not attach activity history for people CC'd on the email?

Tags: email, emailtosalesforce

I found Salesforce documentation that says:

> If you configure Email to Salesforce to associate emails to matching
>   leads or contacts, Salesforce searches the To and CC fields for the
>   email addresses of your leads or contacts. If any leads or contacts
>   are found, Salesforce saves the email to the Activity History related
>   list on the appropriate record.

Is it possible to have Salesforce only search the To field and not the CC field?

Most of the time, people in the CC column are other staff members who do not need the email added to their Salesforce Activity History.

Comment: You could write a trigger to immediately delete them upon creation.

Comment: @caleb.breckon Thanks. Can you recommend any documentation to help me do this?

Comment: The only relevant documentation would be just googling Apex Triggers. It's going to be a generic trigger after insert on EmailMessage, then you'll need to do some logic using either ccIds or ccAddress and parentid and the associated contact to compare.